# Go code building linker error. Can I link manually?

Tags: go, linker, cgo

I am building Go code that uses CGo heavily and this code **must** be compiled into a shared or static library (static is highly preferred). ([code for reference](https://github.com/akamensky/cgo-example))

It all works just fine on Linux and Mac, but on Windows it fails on linker stage either saying that all 4 modes (c-shared, shared, c-archive, archive) are not available or if invoke `go tool link -shared` manually complains about missing windows specific instructions.

My understanding is that all I need to build usable *lib.a* is to compile everything I will use into object files (*.o) and then put it through `ar` to produce usable static library.

Now the question is whether I can completely skip Go's linker and based on prepared `.o` files create `.a` manually?

How would I go about doing that if that is even possible?

Comment: Where are you getting these "prepared `.o` files" to build into a static library? See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11058 for the details of the Windows issue.

Comment: @JimB the .o files are coming from the Go itself when it calls cgo. You can run an example code with `-x` argument so it will show you everything it is doing under the hood and then you can break that flow down to manual execution by calling `go tool [tool] [arguments]` and calling `gcc [arguments]` because this is what Go with CGo code does.

Comment: @JimB Also if you look at the issue you linked it is still open, means it was not resolved. However as I write in my own answer I had to build latest master branch of Go code to be able to compile everything successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gcc on windows is unable to automatically discover necessary shared libraries. The problem was caused by GCC and not by Go.

Although for compiling Go I had to use self-compiled master tip as current release (1.6.2) does not support shared/static libraries on windows/amd64.

Manually feeding gcc with each shared library (ntdll, winmm etc) in default location (C:\Windows\SysWOW64) has fixed the problem.